# Matlab doesn't save the new dimension of the plot

Tags: matlab, plot, window-resize

I'm trying to save a figure with a no-default dimension, but I always obtain the default size plot.

```
    figure 
    for i=1:6 
        for j=1:4 
            subplot(6,4,j+(i-1)*4)
            [...]
        end
    end    
    w=600; h=800;
    set(gcf,'Position',[30 60 w h]);
    set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'centimeters');
    set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','manual')
    print('test','-depsc');
```

It is mainly a 6-by-4 subplot. I looked for a solution on internet, I found many comments about `Position`, `PaperUnits`, `PaperPositionMode`, but none has worked so far. The only solution that works is when I export as .fig.

What I actually realized, is that after the `set(gcf,'Position',[30 60 w h])` the window dimension of the plot is correct, but the subplot are squeezed like when the dimension is the default. If I just insert a `pause` and manually resize the window (even by almost nothing), the subplots expand nicely within the larger window. But still, with the `print` command the result is not the desired one.

I tried also with `saveas` and I got the same result.

Ah, if I manually save the figure, it works perfectly, but, of course, I need to automatize the process!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In general, if you want matlab to save stuff properly, use FEX submission `export_fig`

Comment: That said, `paperUnits` are options for the figure when printed in paper.

Comment: Changing the `Position` attribute of the figure will only change the size of the figure itself (i.e. only the window surrounding your plots). To change your plots sizes, you have to loop over the children of your figure, and more precisely over the children of type `axes`. This is exactly what Matlab does when you "manually" resize the figure

Comment: @BillBokeey can you give me an example please?

Comment: Will you be able to generalize if i give you an example with 2 subplots?

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: My version is the R2012b

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95451/discussion-between-billbokeey-and-sfrow).

Comment: @Sfrow did you try inserting a `drawnow` statement where you included the `pause` statement?

Comment: @Matt17, yes I just tried, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Although i can't reproduce this behaviour as MATLAB 2014b automatically handles axes resizing, i'll still post an answer, that may need some adjustments.

Basically, what you need to do is :

```
% Get a handle to your figure object
Myfig=gcf;

% Get all of your figure Children - Warning : if you have a global
% legend in your figure, it will belong to your figure Children and you
% ll have to ignore it
AllChildren=get(Myfig,'Children');
MyAxes=findobj(AllChildren,'type','axes');

% Now you have your axes objects, whose Position attributes should be in
% normalized units. What you need to do now is to store these positions 
% before changing the size of your figure, to reapply them after
% resizing (the beauty of normalized positions).
Positions=zeros(size(MyAxes,1),4);

for ii=1:size(MyAxes,1)

  Positions(ii,:)=get(MyAxes(ii),'Position');

end

% Resize your figure
w=600;
h=800;
set(gcf,'Position',[30 60 w h]);

% Reuse the positions you stored to resize your subplots
for ii=1:size(MyAxes,1)

  set(MyAxes(ii),'Position',Positions(ii,:));

end
```

This should do the trick.